# How to get values from multiple asp literals and set as jquery lightbox description

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a grid of user details being iterated and populated into aspLiterals and shows in the grid, image of user links to a lightbox, but I need to add the user details to the lightbox aswell

I tried getting the values using below code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="tt">
  <asp:HyperLink ID="Title" runat="server" CssClass="title" />
</h3>
<span id="ss"><asp:Literal ID="Address" runat="server" /></span>
<span id="rr"><strong>Tel : </strong><asp:Literal ID="Workphone" runat="server" /></span>
<span id="oo"><strong>Cel : </strong><asp:Literal ID="Cellphone" runat="server" /></span>
<span id="pp"><asp:HyperLink ID="Email" runat="server" /></span>
</br>
<span id="ii" class="partners">  <asp:Literal ID="Architects" runat="server" /></span>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photo').click(function() {
      //Get
      var v = $('.title, .address, .workphone, .cellphone, .email, .architects').html();
      console.log(v);
      //Setters
    })
  });
</script>
```

To show strings of text from literals using jquery to lightbox description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP control's id is changed when it's render.So you must public your ASP control. For example:

```
let your-component = <%= [Your-ASP-Control]; %>
```

In your case `Literal` and `HyperLink` is different thing.

For `HyperLink`:

```
let Title = <%= [Title]; %>  //For HyperLink 
let TitleURL = $(Title).attr('href');
```

For `Literal`:

```
let Address= <%= [Address]; %>  //For Literal
let GetAddress= $(Address).text();
```